# How to prevent the creation of annoying .DS_Store files?

Tags: mac, finder, mojave

I am working on a MacBook Air (10.14.6), using network mounted filesystems. It then happens that for no reason at all files like

```
.DS_Store
._.DS_Store
```

appear randomly in folders, breaking my workflow. This is especially annoying if they appear in a git repository and you have to remove them manually.

Therefore my simple question:

**How can I prevent once and for all the creation of these useless and annoying files?**

An answer provided in another thread was to use the following commands:

```
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool true
defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteUSBStores -bool true
```

Maybe it does work for network mounted filesystems, but for the local filesystem it does not seem to work.

Comment: @fsb It does not seem to answer my question. The github seems to be outdated.

Comment: Try the answer by LаngLаngС in the link Allan provided.

Comment: @user3439894 Ok just tried this. Now I need to see for a few days if this behavior is fixed. Do I have to reissue these commands on a reboot? Or are they 'fixed'?

Comment: RE: "Do I have to reissue these commands on a reboot? Or are they 'fixed'?" -- Settings such as these are set until modified or deleted from the target _file_.

Comment: @user3439894 Using `defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool true` and `defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteUSBStores -bool true` does not solve my problem. The files are back!